# Problem displaying Chinese text in Textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, character-encoding

I need to display chinese text from an Api(GET) into a textview.

The field from which text is fetched is -> "deliveryFirstName": "莊欣瑜".

The text "deliveryFirstName": "莊欣瑜" is only correctly shown in postman.

But in Android studio log, it is displayed as "deliveryFirstName": "èæ¬£ç"

But when i display this in textview what i get is some boxes like this èæ¬£ç.

The charset used in backend is utf8mb4 and collation is utf8_mb4_collation_ci.

I have tried using

```
Html.fromHtml()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally got the solution. Just made sure that the "UTF-8" encoded sting is what i get as response from volley. This fixed the problem.

```
public class Utf8JSONRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {
public Utf8JSONRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray requestJSON, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, String.valueOf(requestJSON), listener, errorListener);
}

@Override
protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse networkResponse) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(networkResponse.data, "UTF-8");
        return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(networkResponse));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source code in case you are using volley's `StringRequest`

```
public class Utf8StringRequest extends StringRequest {

  public Utf8StringRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
  }

  @Override
  protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

    try {
        String String = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
        return Response.success(String,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're left doing one of two things.

Adding the Unicode character within java to the String in the XML file:

```
String str = "\u00A9" + getContext().getString(R.string.your_string);
```

Entering the text as HTML in java:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your chars"));
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Since the content might be chinese or english as per API result. Is it ok to add the two steps mentioned ?.